# Freeing Allocated Memory From A Struct

Tags: c, memory, memory-management, struct

I am sending a struct Food to the function thats job is to free the allocated memory of the struct but not the struct itself.

The struct looks like this:

```
struct Food{
char * name;
char * foodGroup;
double calories;
char type;
struct Food * next;
};
```

The char *name and char *foodGroup are memory allocated in another function.

```
struct Food* temp = malloc(sizeof(struct Food));
temp->name = malloc(sizeof(temp->name));       /*ERROR?*/
temp->foodGroup = malloc(sizeof(temp->name));  /*ERROR?*/
temp->next = malloc(sizeof(struct Food));
```

The function that frees the allocated memory looks like this:

```
void destroyElement(Food *theElement)
{
    free(theElement->name);  /*ERROR*/
    free(theElement->foodGroup);   /*ERROR*/
}
```

I used print statements to determine the location of the segmentation fault and it looks like its in the `destroyElement` function.

Comment: You're probably causing heap corruption elsewhere in the program. The line `temp->name = malloc(sizeof(temp->name));` is very suspicious. This probably allocates 4 bytes. Is the rest of your code making sure not to overflow this buffer?

Comment: To get good help post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: For more accurate results, use a debugger. Print statements can be misleading.

Comment: You've referred to `struct Food` with the prefix `struct` keyword everywhere except for in the `destroyElement` function. Technically speaking, this doesn't even compile, and your question should be about some compiler error message which you haven't mentioned. I second @MattMcNabb's request for a MCVE, and vote for closure, on the grounds that the problem can't be reproduced, until an MCVE is provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `malloc(sizeof(temp->name))`, try `malloc(sizeof(thing you want to put in temp->name)`.

It seems like you are trying to take `sizeof(temp->name)`, the thing you were trying to malloc in the first place (if `temp->name` is being malloced right now, what is it's size?)

Does this make sense?

If not, feel free to email Judi, or ask on Bucky. ;)

Answer (score 0):

user3711622 is right when they said that malloc line is incorrect. In the createRecord function you feed in *name as well as *group. The best way to do it would be to change 
`temp->name = malloc(sizeof(temp->name));` 
to 
`temp->name = malloc(sizeof(char) * strlen(name));`

Technically you could use the value 26 instead of strlen(name) because Judi said that she would never have a name in the test file that is greater than 25 characters, but like Judi always tells us, defensive programming is good programming.